# codeigniter 4 mysql query builder get subdata from itself

Tags: php, mysql, query-builder, codeigniter-4, codeigniter-query-builder

[UPDATED]

the error is now gone but the data result from the codeigniter 4 query builder all has the same `id` value, unlike the one in phpmyadmin. and if I use the `$builder` method it now gives the expected result, but I'm still hoping to be able to fully use the query builder properly if possible..

---

I have a mysql table like this

```
id | nama | hari
-----------------
1  | AAA  | 1
2  | AAA  | 2
3  | AAA  | 3
4  | AAA  | 4
5  | AAA  | 5
6  | BBB  | 1
7  | BBB  | 2
8  | BBB  | 3
```

when I get a parameter `id` 1, I want to get the row number 1-5 only. it works when I use this sql in phpmyadmin

```
select m.* 
from m_rute m
join (
    select m1.*
    from m_rute m1
    where m1.id = 1
) mt on mt.nama_rute = m.nama_rute
```

[image: result from sql in phpmyadmin]

then I try to "translate" it using codeigniter 4's query builder but when I test it on postman, it gives a set of data where all the `id` field is the same, unlike the one in phpmyadmin result.

controller

```
public function show($id = null)
{
    $db = \Config\Database::connect();
    $builder = $db->table('m_rute as m');
    $builder->select('m.*')->where('m.id', $id);
    $subquery = $builder->getCompiledSelect();

    // this works but wouldn't a fully proper query builder seem nicer?
    //////////////
    // $builder->select('m.*')
    //     ->join('('.$subquery.') as m1', 'm1.nama_rute = m.nama_rute')
    //     ;
    // $q = $builder->get();
    // $data = $q->getResultArray();

    $model = new MRuteModel();

    $model->join('('.$subquery.') as t', 't.nama_rute = m_rute.nama_rute');

    $data  = $model->findAll();

    if (!$data) {
        return $this->failNotFound('Data not found');
    }

    return $this->respond($data);
}
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution 1: Using [Raw/Regular Queries](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#regular-queries).

> The `query()` function returns a database result **object** when
> “read” type queries are run which you can use to [show your
> results](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html).
> When “write” type queries are run it simply returns `true` or `false`
> depending on success or failure.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class MRuteModel extends Model
{
    public function findById(int $id)
    {
        $id = $this->db->escape($id);

        return $this->db->query("
            select m.* 
            from m_rute m
                join (
                    select m1.*
                    from m_rute m1
                    where m1.id = {$id}
                ) mt on mt.nama_rute = m.nama_rute")->getResultArray();
    }
}
```

#### Solution 2A: Using [SQL Joins](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=join#join) With Raw Queries.

> `join($table, $cond[, $type = ''[, $escape = null]])`
>    **Parameters:**
>
> **$table** (string) – Table name
> to join
>
> **$cond** (string) – The
> JOIN ON condition
>
> **$type**
> (string) – The JOIN type
>
> **$escape** (bool) – Whether to
> escape values and identifiers
>
> **Returns:**    `BaseBuilder` instance (method
> chaining)
>
> **Return type:**    `BaseBuilder`
>
> Adds a `JOIN` clause to a query.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class MRuteModel extends Model
{
    public function findById(int $id)
    {
        $id = $this->db->escape($id);

        return $this->db->table('m_rute m')
            ->select("m.*")
            ->join("
            (select m1.*
                from m_rute m1
                    where m1.id = {$id}
            ) mt", 'mt.nama_rute = m.nama_rute')
            ->get()->getResultArray();
    }
}
```

#### Solution 2B: Using [SQL Joins](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=join#join) With A Query Builder.

[`getCompiledSelect()`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=getcompiledselect#getCompiledSelect)

> Compiles a `SELECT` statement and returns it as a string.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class MRuteModel extends Model
{
    public function findById(int $id)
    {
        $subQuery = $this->db->table('m_rute m1')
            ->select("m1.*")
            ->where("m1.id", $id)
            ->getCompiledSelect();

        return $this->db->table('m_rute m')
            ->select("m.*")
            ->join("($subQuery) mt", 'mt.nama_rute = m.nama_rute')
            ->get()
            ->getResultArray();
    }
}
```

#### Solution 3A: Using A [`where` Clause](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=join#where) With A Closure.

> `where($key[, $value = null[, $escape = null]])`
>    **Parameters:**
>
> **$key** (mixed) – Name of field to compare, or associative array
>
> **$value** (mixed) – If a single key, compared to this value
>
> **$escape**
> (bool) – Whether to escape values and identifiers
>
> **Returns:**    `BaseBuilder` instance (method
> chaining)
>
> **Return type:**    `BaseBuilder`
>
> Generates the `WHERE` portion of the query. Separates multiple calls with `AND`.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;
use CodeIgniter\Database\BaseBuilder;

class MRuteModel extends Model
{
    public function findById(int $id)
    {
        // With a closure.
        return $this->db->table('m_rute')
            ->where('nama_rute =', function (BaseBuilder $builder) use ($id) {
                return $builder->select("nama_rute")->from("m_rute")
                    ->where("id", $id);
            })
            ->get()
            ->getResultArray();
    }
}
```

#### Solution 3B: Using A [`where` Clause](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=join#where) With A Builder.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class MRuteModel extends Model
{
    public function findById(int $id)
    {
        $subQuery = $this->db->table('m_rute m1')
            ->select("m1.nama_rute")
            ->where("m1.id", $id)
            ->getCompiledSelect();

        // With a builder.
        return $this->db->table('m_rute')
            ->where("nama_rute =($subQuery)")
            ->get()
            ->getResultArray();
    }
}
```